# Why does `IsSorted` in the standard library iterate over the slice in reverse?

Tags: performance, go, benchmarking

Out of curiosity, I've been looking at the source of both the [`sort`](https://pkg.go.dev/sort) package in the standard library and the experimental [`slices`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices) package which is soon to be [added to the standard library](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/57433). Both packages define an `IsSorted` function, where they check whether a list is sorted by verifying adjacent elements are ordered. However, this is done in *reverse*.

I created a little reproduction, loosely based on the generic `slices` package. My experiments do show that the *reverse* version is faster.

```golang
func IsSortedForward[T any](slice []T, compare func(a, b T) int) bool {
    for i := 0; i < len(slice) - 1; i++ {
        if compare(slice[i], slice[i+1]) > 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func IsSortedForward2[T any](slice []T, compare func(a, b T) int) bool {
    n := len(slice) - 1
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        if compare(slice[i], slice[i+1]) > 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func IsSortedReverse[T any](slice []T, compare func(a, b T) int) bool {
    for i := len(slice) - 1; i > 0; i-- {
        if compare(slice[i], slice[i-1]) < 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

My initial thought is that the forward version would be more "cache-friendly". However, I did notice one advantage of the reverse version as `len(slice) - 1` is only computed once. Whereas, in the forward version it is computed on each iteration. My assumption is that this is why the reverse version is marginally faster.

I then extracted `len(slice) - 1` outside of the loop in the forward version, so that it is only computed once, which did improve its performance. However, it was still marginally slower than the reverse version. My guess is that the comparison `i > 0` in the reverse version (with zero) is faster than the comparison with `i < n` in the forward version?

*Why do you think the reverse version is faster? Why is the adjusted forward version still not as fast as the reverse version?*

EDIT: I didn't know that the Compiler Explorer (Godbolt) works with Go... Here is a [little reproduction](https://godbolt.org/z/cGv5Mfxv1) of the functions addressed in this question. It appears that Go has its own [assembly language](https://go.dev/doc/asm)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In short: because more efficient code can be generated from a downward loop, specifically for the condition part.

***Personal note:** Should you use it in your own code? Not if performance is not critical. Use a loop that is more readable and makes sense. There is obvious gain using the faster version in the standard library (as everyone is using it), but just for a few microseconds don't sacrifice readability in your code.*

`IsSortedForward2()` and `IsSortedReverse()` are more or less the same except that the former uses an increment operator (`i++`) and `i+1` inside the body, the latter uses a decrement operator (`i--`) and `i-1` inside the body, these are equivalent in terms of performance.

The noticeable difference comes from the condition: the forward variant uses `i < n`, and the reverse variant uses `i > 0`. The first requires comparing 2 variables, the latter requires comparing one variable to a very special value: 0.

In general the first condition requires loading 2 variables (memory locations) to registers and comparing their values. The latter requires loading 1 variable to a register and comparing it to the special 0 value. Note that in practice these variables may live in registers, so an actual memory load may not have to happen.

You can check the generated assembly code by running:

```
go tool compile -S play.go > play.s
```

The source lines I used:

```
20 func IsSortedForward2[T any](slice []T, compare func(a, b T) int) bool {
21     n := len(slice) - 1
22     for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
23          if compare(slice[i], slice[i+1]) > 0 {
24              return false
25          }
26     }
27     return true
28 }
29 
30 func IsSortedReverse[T any](slice []T, compare func(a, b T) int) bool {
31     for i := len(slice) - 1; i > 0; i-- {
32         if compare(slice[i], slice[i-1]) < 0 {
33             return false
34         }
35     }
36     return true
37 }
```

The interesting lines are 22 and 31, here are the generated assembly for those lines:

```
play.go:22) JMP     77
play.go:22) MOVQ    main.n+16(SP), DI
play.go:22) MOVQ    main.compare+80(SP), SI
play.go:22) MOVQ    main.slice+64(SP), CX
play.go:22) MOVQ    main.slice+56(SP), BX
play.go:22) MOVQ    main..autotmp_9+24(SP), AX
play.go:22) CMPQ    AX, DI
play.go:22) JGE     136

play.go:31) DECQ    CX
play.go:31) JMP     53
play.go:32) MOVQ    main.i+16(SP), CX
play.go:32) DECQ    CX
play.go:32) MOVQ    main.slice+48(SP), BX
play.go:32) MOVQ    main.compare+72(SP), SI
play.go:31) TESTQ   CX, CX
play.go:31) JLE     100
play.go:31) MOVQ    CX, main.i+16(SP)
```

`IsSortedForward2()` loads `i` and `n` into `AX` and `DI` registers, and compares them using `CMPQ`.

`IsSortedReverse()` only has to load `i` into `CX`, and tests if it's zero using `TESTQ`.

Comment: @scottwillmoore: A smarter compiler would have put `decq cx` / `jge top_of_loop` at the bottom of the loop, since `dec` sets FLAGS.  Also, it wouldn't store RCX to memory every iteration!  It would keep the loop counter in a call-preserved register (since the loop includes a call through a function pointer.)  Of course, at many call-sites `compare` would be a constant so `IsSortedReverse` could inline, and `compare` could inline into the loop.  Anyway, yes if you have a compiler that can't optimize well, making the source closer to efficient asm can help.

Comment: A lot of these optimizations no longer apply to current CPUs or are counterproductive there -- for [example](https://godbolt.org/z/qKMhe5Ecz), on POWER checking the overflow flag after a multiplication is more expensive than doing another multiplication.

Comment: @SimonRichter: What optimization in this answer are you talking about?  Eliminating instructions from a loop (when keeping the other instructions the same cost) is still a useful optimization.  It's not so much about the CPU here, it's about a compiler that's much worse than GCC / Clang at optimizing.  (And a non-inline function call inside the loop can defeat optimizations like hoisting the size if it's possible that the function could change the `.size` of the pointed-to object via another reference to it.  So doing it manually is still good.)

Comment: @PeterCordes According to [Quick Guide to Go's Assembler](https://go.dev/doc/asm), Go's "compiler operates on a semi-abstract instruction set, and instruction selection occurs partly after code generation". In other words, some optimizations take place even though they are not seen in the assembly code.

Comment: @dev.bmax: I don't think they're saying that Go's assembler does further *optimization*.  They're talking about pseudo-instructions, like MIPS `li $t0, 0x1234567` which would assemble to `lui $t0, 0x123` / `addiu $t0, 0x4567` with standard MIPS assemblers.  Go might use different syntax, but the same concept.  In this case, all the x86-64 instructions in the Go asm listing map directly to a single x86-64 machine instruction, e.g. `CMPQ    AX, DI` in Go syntax is `cmp %rax, %rdi` in AT&T syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Beyond [icza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76811314/364696) (which is quite good, and applies in general), operating in reverse is more likely to allow an early-out short-circuiting in specific semi-common use cases (and costs nothing when it doesn't help). Many high level languages, including Go, don't provide a sorted container type, so maintaining a sorted data structure is painful with the built-ins + standard library alone (even if you provide a binary search package for whatever contiguous data sequence type it provides, e.g. Go's `slice`, it only reduces the search work to `O(log n)`, insertion remains `O(n)`).

To account for this, it's assumed that, when a user needs a sorted data structure that is infrequently modified, they'll just append on new data rather than inserting in sorted order, and if any new data has been added since it was last sorted, it will be sorted before the next operation on it that requires it to be sorted. The sorting algorithms for the language often optimize for this, e.g. Python's [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) handles "mostly sorted, with a few unsorted elements" in close to `O(n)` time, and Go's modern `sort.Sort` (based on [pdqsort (pattern-defeating quick sort)](https://github.com/orlp/pdqsort)) is `O(n)` if a single element has been added to the end (though I'm unclear on whether that's a special case vs. a general ability to take advantage of existing ordering when more than one element is out of place).

In these "mostly sorted, sometimes with a few unsorted elements at the end" scenario, when `IsSorted` is called, there's two possibilities:

1. The `slice` is already sorted (nothing has been added since it was last sorted, or the new elements happened to preserve order), or
2. The beginning of the `slice` (likely *most* of the `slice`) is sorted, but there are a (typically small) number of unsorted elements at the end.

In case #1, the entire `slice` must be checked no matter which direction you operate in before it eventually returns true, so the order you check in won't matter. But in case #2, assuming the new elements are semi-randomly ordered, operating in reverse means you'll be able to short-circuit and return false almost immediately, while operating in forward order means you'll have to recheck that the (assumed much larger) number of sorted elements remain sorted before hitting the smaller number of unsorted elements at the end and short-circuiting a much smaller amount of work.

---

To clear up a misconception, cache-wise, operating sequentially in forward or reverse order doesn't typically make a difference; sequential access patterns, regardless of direction, are handled well on modern systems.

Comment: There can be small advantages to forward traversal. In Intel CPUs, the most important prefetcher, the L2 "streamer", can detect sequential or small-stride streams in either direction.  But I seem to recall the L1d prefetcher is biased towards increasing addresses.  So it's definitely not a disaster to loop backwards, but *if* all else is equal (unlike in this case), looping forwards is preferable.  With a pointer and end-pointer (optimizing away the loop counter), the asm is the same either way, just `+n` vs. `-n` in the pointer increment and comparing against an end-pointer in a reg.